# How can I `find` files matching pattern within a directory matching another pattern from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, locate

Say I want to find all files in `/Path` named `file_name*`. Easy:

```
$ find /Path -name "file_name*"
/Path/foo1/file_name1.txt
/Path/foo2/file_name2.txt
/Path/bar3/file_name3.txt
/Path/bar4/file_name4.txt
```

What if I only want to search subdirectories like `bar`?

I could pipe the results, but this is highly inefficient.

```
$ find /Path -name "file_name*" | grep "bar"
/Path/bar3/file_name3.txt
/Path/bar4/file_name4.txt
```

**Is there a way to get them all in the `find` and to skip searching directories not matching `bar`?**

*Note:* If I search `/Path/bar3` specifically results come back instantly. But if I search just `/Path` and then `grep` for `bar` it takes 30-60 seconds. This is why piping to `grep` isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use a wildcard in the `-name` parameter but you can also use it in the path parameter.

```
find /Path/bar* -name "file_name*"
```

I created the following test directory:

```
./Path
|-- bar
    `-- file_name123.txt
|-- bar1
    `-- file_name234.txt
|-- bar2
    `-- file_name345.txt
|-- foo
    `-- file_name456.txt
```

The above command gives:

```
Path/bar/file_name123.txt
Path/bar1/file_name234.txt
Path/bar2/file_name345.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `-path` flag like

```
find /Path -path "/Path/bar*" -name "file_name*"
```

This lets you do multiple paths where there isn't an easy wildcard like

```
find /PATH \( -path "/Path/bar*" -o -path "/Path/foo* \) -name "file_name*"
```